# How to correctly redefine the CSS settings for FireFox?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have the following problem with CSS.

I have to define this style that have to be applied only if the used browser is **FireFox)

```
body {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #E9FDE9;
    color: #696969;
    size: 12px;
}
```

So the CSS setting for the **body** tag have to be redifined only if the browser is FireFox.

I know that for IE I can use the conditional comment...but for FireFox?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem (i.e. you have a problem and you think that introducing this behaviour will solve it). So, what is the actual problem? By the way, the answers below will also affect lots of other browsers except Firefox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
    @-moz-document url-prefix() { 
       body {
         text-align: center;
         background-color: #E9FDE9;
         color: #696969;
         size: 12px;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

For Chrome Firefox and IE

```
   <style type='text/css'>
    /*This will work for chrome */
    #categoryBackNextButtons
    {
        width:490px;
    }
    /*This will work for firefox*/
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
        #categoryBackNextButtons{
            width:486px;
        }
    }
    </style>
    <!--[if IE]>
    <style type='text/css'>
    /*This will work for IE*/
    #categoryBackNextButtons
    {
        width:486px;
    }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
```